# How to preserve request body on performing HTTP redirect from servlet filter

Tags: java, http-post, servlet-filters

I have a Java web application deployed on 2 host machines, fronted by a servlet filter. I sent a POST request to the application on one host, which is intercepted by the filter and redirected to the other host:

```java
public void doFilter (ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
       FilterChain filterChain)
{
    ...
    if(shouldRedirect) {
        httpResponse.sendRedirect(redirectLocation);
    }
}
```

On the second machine, the request passes the filter and is handled by a REST API in a Resource class.

```java
@POST
public Response handleRequest(InputStream stream)
{
    ...
}
```

The `stream` object is sent as part of the POST request body. After the redirection, the request body is not sent over and `stream` is empty. How do I preserve the request body (or at least this part of it) after the redirect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would perform a post to the redirectLocation instead. sendRedirect is telling the client to change its location so you are starting a new HTTP request at that point.

When you perform the redirect you could have the client initiate the original POST request to the new URL.

Answer (score 7):

Another method I found could work is a 307 (Temporary redirect). This preserves the body of the original request, so it works in this case. The 307 redirect has some security implications as detailed [here](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/post-redirect.html), but there is the benefit of not having the original host acting as a proxy for a blocking HTTP request.

```java
public void doFilter(...)
{
    ...
    httpResponse.setStatus(TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
    httpResponse.setHeader("Location", redirectLocation);
    return;
}
```

Comment: thx, this is a great answer, worked for my request that also had a body with some data

Answer (score 2):

`sendRedirect()` re-visits the user's browser and from browser makes a visit to the re-directed url.

having said that, the POST data is available only at the initial host where the `first request` has been recievied. i.e. filter in this case.

What you can do :

modify your redirect url to include POST data as `Request Parameters in GET url`

e.g. `host2\servlet?param=one&param2=two`

Read more about [URL Redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection)